# Why does let not allow mutually recursive definitions, whereas letrec can?

Tags: scheme, evaluation, let, letrec

I suspect that I fundamentally misunderstand Scheme's evaluation rules. What is it about the way that `let` and `letrec` are coded and evaluated that makes `letrec` able to accept mutually recursive definitions whereas `let` cannot? Appeals to their basic `lambda` forms may be helpful.

Comment: `lambda` and `application` are enough to implement both `let` and `letrec`.  But because you want to write more condensed, you use `let` and `letrec`, depending on situation.

Comment: @alinsoar surely writing Y-based code for mutual recursion is torturous.

Comment: @WillNess `Y` can be derived using syntactical rewritings from `omega` *x=>x.x*.  I use omega all the time, Y almost never.

Comment: @alinsoar you're right, it's easy with U-like explicit arguments. I used it in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let` can't create mutually-recursive functions in any obvious way because you can always turn `let` into `lambda`:

```
(let ((x 1))
  ...)
-->
((λ (x)
   ...)
 1)
```

and similarly for more than one binding:

```
(let ((x 1)
      (y 2))
  ...)
-->
((λ (x y)
   ...)
 1 2)
```

Here and below, `-->` means 'can be translated into' or even 'could be macroexpanded into'.

OK, so now consider the case where the `x` and `y` are functions:

```
(let ((x (λ (...) ...))
      (y (λ (...) ...)))
  ...)
-->
((λ (x y)
   ...)
 (λ (...) ...)
 (λ (...) ...))
```

And now it's becoming fairly clear why this can't work for recursive functions:

```
(let ((x (λ (...) ... (y ...) ...))
      (y (λ (...) ... (x ...) ...)))
  ...)
-->
((λ (x y)
   ...)
 (λ (...) (y ...) ...)
 (λ (...) (x ...) ...))
```

Well, let's make this more concrete to see what goes wrong: let's consider a *single* recursive function: if there's a problem with that then there certainly will be problems with sets of mutually recursive functions.

```
(let ((factorial (λ (n)
                   (if (= n 1) 1
                       (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))))
  (factorial 10))
-->
((λ (factorial)
   (factorial 10))
 (λ (n)
   (if (= n 1) 1
       (* n (factorial (- n 1))))))
```

OK, what happens when you try to evaluate the form?  We can use the environment model as described in [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-21.html#%_sec_3.2) .  In particular consider evaluating this form in an environment, *e*, in which there is no binding for `factorial`. Here's the form:

```
((λ (factorial)
   (factorial 10))
 (λ (n)
   (if (= n 1) 1
       (* n (factorial (- n 1))))))
```

Well, this is just a function application with a single argument, so to evaluate this you simply evaluate, in some order, the function form and its argument.

Start with the function form:

```
(λ (factorial)
  (factorial 10))
```

This just evaluates to a function which, when called, will:

1. create an environment *e'* which extends *e* with a binding of `factorial` to the argument of the function;
2. call whatever is bound to `factorial` with the argument `10` and return the result.

So now we have to evaluate the argument, again in the environment *e*:

```
(λ (n)
  (if (= n 1) 1
      (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))
```

This evaluates to a function of one argument which, when called, will:

1. establish an environment *e''* which extends *e* with a binding of `n` to the argument of the function;
2. if the argument isn't `1`, will try to call some function bound to a variable called `factorial`, looking up this binding in *e''*.

Hold on: what function?  There is no binding of `factorial` in *e*, and *e''* extends *e* (in particular, *e''* does *not* extend *e'*), but by adding a binding of `n`, not `factorial`.  Thus there is no binding of `factorial` in *e''*.  So this function is an error: you will either get an error when it's evaluated or you'll get an error when it's called, depending on how smart the implementation is.

Instead, you need to do something like this to make this work:

```
(let ((factorial (λ (n) (error "bad doom"))))
  (set! factorial
        (λ (n)
          (if (= n 1) 1
              (* n (factorial (- n 1))))))
  (factorial 10))
-->
((λ (factorial)
   (set! factorial
         (λ (n)
           (if (= n 1) 1
               (* n (factorial (- n 1))))))
   (factorial 10))
 (λ (n) (error "bad doom")))
```

This will now work.  Again, it's a function application, but this time all the action happens in the function:

```
(λ (factorial)
  (set! factorial
        (λ (n)
          (if (= n 1) 1
              (* n (factorial (- n 1))))))
  (factorial 10))
```

So, evaluating this in *e* results in a function which, when called will:

1. create an environment *e'*, extending *e*, in which there is a binding of `factorial` to whatever its argument is;
2. *mutate* the binding of `factorial` in *e'*, assigning a different value to it;
3. call the value of `factorial` in *e'*, with argument `10`, returning the result.

So the interesting step is (2): the new value of `factorial` is the value of this form, evaluated in *e'*:

```
(λ (n)
  (if (= n 1) 1
      (* n (factorial (- n 1)))
```

Well, this again is a function which, when called, will:

1. create an environent, *e''*, which extends *e'* (NOTE!) with a binding for `n`;
2. if the value of the binding of `n` is not `1`, call whatever is bound to `factorial` in the *e''* environment.

And now this will work, because there *is* a binding of `factorial` in *e''*, because, now, *e''* extends *e'* and there is a binding of `factorial` in *e'*.  And, further, by the time the function is called, *e'* will have been mutated so that the binding is the correct one: it's the function itself.

And this is in fact more-or-less how `letrec` is defined.  In a form like

```
(letrec ((a <f1>)
         (b <f2>))
  ...)
```

First the variables, `a` and `b` are bound to some undefined values (it is an error ever to refer to these values).  *Then* `<f1>` and `<f2>` are evaluated in some order, in the resulting environment (this evaluation should not refer to the values that `a` and `b` have at that point), and the results of these evaluations are *assigned* to `a` and `b` respectively, mutating their bindings and finally the body is evaluated in the resulting environment.

See for instance [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.4.6) (other reports are similar but harder to refer to as most of them are PDF):

> The <variable>s are bound to fresh locations, the <init>s are evaluated in the resulting environment (in some unspecified order), each <variable> is assigned to the result of the corresponding <init>, the <body> is evaluated in the resulting environment, and the values of the last expression in <body> are returned. Each binding of a <variable> has the entire `letrec` expression as its region, making it possible to define mutually recursive procedures.

This is obviously something similar to what `define` must do, and in fact I think it's clear that, for internal `define` at least, you can always turn `define` into `letrec`:

```
(define (outer a)
  (define (inner b)
    ...)
  ...)
-->
(define (outer a)
  (letrec ((inner (λ (b) ...)))
    ...))
```

And perhaps this is the same as

```
(letrec ((outer
          (λ (a)
            (letrec ((inner
                      (λ (b)
                        ...)))
              ...)))))
```

But I am not sure.

---

Of course, `letrec` buys you no computational power (neither does `define`): you can define recursive functions without it, it's just less convenient:

```
(let ((facter
       (λ (c n)
         (if (= n 1)
             1
             (* n (c c (- n 1)))))))
  (let ((factorial
         (λ (n)
           (facter facter n))))
    (factorial 10)))
```

or, for the pure of heart:

```
((λ (facter)
   ((λ (factorial)
      (factorial 10))
    (λ (n)
      (facter facter n))))
 (λ (c n)
   (if (= n 1)
       1
       (* n (c c (- n 1))))))
```

This is pretty close to the U combinator, or I always think it is.

---

Finally, it's reasonably easy to write a quick-and-dirty `letrec` as a macro.  Here's one called `labels` (see the comments to this answer):

```
(define-syntax labels
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ ((var init) ...) form ...)
     (let ((var (λ x (error "bad doom"))) ...)
       (set! var init) ...
       form ...)]))
```

This will work for conforming uses, but it can't make referring to the initial bindings of the variables is an error: *calling* them is, but they can leak out.  Racket, for instance, does some magic which makes this be an error.

Comment: "...other reports are similar...": `letrec` first appears with essentially its current definition on page 16 of [R2RS](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/5600/AIM-848.pdf) (1985); _SCHEME: An Interpreter for Extended Lambda Calculus_ (Sussman & Steele, 1975) [[R0RS](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/5794/AIM-349.pdf)] defines `LABELS` (effectively letrec) on page 2.

Comment: @mnemenaut: thanks!  I had forgotten it was originally `labels` (if I ever knew).  CL still has `labels` for the nearest equivalent form.

Answer (score 4):

The following is `even?` without `let` or `letrec`:

```
(define even?
  ( (lambda (e o)              <------.      ------------.
      (lambda (n) (e n e o))     -----*                  |
      )                                                  |
    (lambda (n e o)                      <------.    <---+
       (if (= n 0) #t (o (- n 1) e o)))    -----*        |
    (lambda (n e o)                        <------.  <---*
       (if (= n 0) #f (e (- n 1) e o)))))    -----*
```

This defines the name `even?` to refer to the result of evaluating the application of the object returned by evaluating the `(lambda (e o) (lambda (n) (e n e o)) )` expression to two objects produced by evaluating the other two `lambda` expressions, the ones in the arguments positions.

Each of the argument `lambda` expressions is well formed, in particular there are no references to undefined names. Each only refers to *its* arguments.

The following is the same `even?`, written with `let` for convenience:

```
(define even?-let-
  (let ((e  (lambda (n e o)                     <------.  <---.
              (if (= n 0) #t (o (- n 1) e o))))   -----*      |
        (o  (lambda (n e o)                     <------.  <---+
              (if (= n 0) #f (e (- n 1) e o))))   -----*      |
        )                                                     |
    (lambda (n) (e n e o)) ))     ----------------------------*
```

But what if we won't pass those `e` and `o` values around as arguments?

```
(define even?-let-wrong-                       ^  ^
  (let ((e  (lambda (n)      <-----------------|--|-------.
              (if (= n 0) #t (o (- n 1)))))  --*  |       |
        (o  (lambda (n)                           |       |
              (if (= n 0) #f (e (- n 1)))))     --*       |
        )                                                 |
    (lambda (n) (e n)) ))      ---------------------------*
```

What are the two names `o` and `e` *inside* the two lambda's `if` expressions refer to now?

They refer to nothing defined in *this* piece of code. They are *"out of scope"*.

Why? It can be seen in the *equivalent* `lambda`-based expression, similar to what we've started with, above:

```
(define even?-wrong-                   ^   ^
  ( (lambda (e o)         <----.   ----|---|---------.
      (lambda (n) (e n))     --*       |   |         |
      )                                |   |         |
    (lambda (n)                        |   |  <------+
       (if (= n 0) #t (o (- n 1)))) ---*   |         |
    (lambda (n)                            |  <------*
       (if (= n 0) #f (e (- n 1)))))) -----*
```

This defines the name `even?-wrong-` to refer to the result of evaluating the application of the object returned by evaluating the `(lambda (e o) (lambda (n) (e n)) )` expression to two objects produced by evaluating the other two `lambda` expressions, the ones in the arguments positions.

But each of them contains a free variable, a name which refers to nothing defined *in its scope*. One contains an undefined `o`, and the other contains an undefined `e`.

Why? Because in the application **`(<A> <B> <C>)`**, each of the three expressions **`<A>`**, **`<B>`**, and **`<C>`** is evaluated in the same scope -- that in which the application itself appears; the *enclosing* scope. And *then* the resulting values are applied to each other (in other words, the function call is made).

A "*scope*" is simply a textual area in a code.

Yet we *need* the `o` in the first argument lambda to refer to the second argument lambda, not anything else (or even worse, nothing at all). Same with the `e` in the second argument lambda, which we *need* to point at the first argument lambda.

---

***`let`*** evaluates its variables' *init expressions* in the *enclosing scope* of the *whole* `let` expression first, and then it creates a fresh  environment frame with its variables' names bound to the values which result from those evaluations. The same thing happens with the equivalent three-lambdas expression evaluation.

***`letrec`***, on the other hand, first creates the fresh environment frame with its variables' names bound to as yet-undefined-values (such that referring to those values is guaranteed to result in an error) and then it evaluates its *init expressions* in *this new self-referential frame*, and then it puts the resulting values into  the bindings for their corresponding names.

Which makes the names inside the lambda expressions refer to the names *inside* the whole `letrec` expression's *scope*. In contrast to the `let`'s referring to the *outer* scope:

```
             ^        ^
             |        |
(let ((e     |        |
        (... o ...))  |
      (o              |
        (............ e .........)))
  .....)
```

does ***not*** work;

```
                  .----------------.
                  |                |
(letrec ((e    <--|--------.       |
           (..... o ...))  |       |
         (o    <-----------|-------*
           (.............. e .........)))
  .....)
```

works fine.

---

Here's an example to further clarify things:

1. consider `((lambda (a b) ....here a is 1.... (set! a 3) ....here a is 3....) 1 2)`

2. now consider `((lambda (a b) .....) (lambda (x) (+ a x)) 2)`.

the two `a`s are *different* -- the argument lambda is ill-defined.

3. now consider `((lambda (a b) ...(set! a (lambda (x) (+ a x))) ...) 1 2)`.

the two `a`s are now the same.

so now it *works*.

Comment: You can also write a variant with curried self, *`(define even? ((lambda (s)(s s)) (lambda (s) (lambda(n) (or (zero? n) (not ((s s) (- n 1))))))))`* and coin a name `rec` for `(s s)`.

Comment: You are defining one recursive name; that's simple. :) I wanted to have several, so, two as a minimum. Instead of thinking how to package/hide it by self-application, I just used the explicit argument-passing.

Comment: That's fine.  I once wrote a parser using 6 continuations, each one calling other one, depending on situation, and all were received as parameters.

Comment: OP: I also wrote many other answers dealing with ["letrec"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+letrec) and ["environment"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+environment). see if anything there further clarifies things.

Comment: So, everything in a `let` or `letrec` expression is looking one scope upwards for their definitions and the genius of `letrec` is that, unlike `let`, it creates said extra scope and defines everything there?

Comment: the init expressions of `let` are evaluated in the enclosing scope of the `let` expression, while the scope of its variables and  body is created inside that, nested; `letrec`'s init expressions are evaluated in the same nested scope as its names and body. something like that. so  `let`'s init expressions' variable references ("names") are looked up "on the outside" whereas `letrec`'s are looked up "on the inside".

Comment: Just to be clear, is evaluation order the primary issue in `even?-wrong-`? That is, does the first to be ran of the `e` and `o` expressions fail because the other has yet to be ran?

Comment: no, what's wrong is the _scope_. the lambdas contain free variables. i.e. undefined, unbound names. every name must be looked up in an environment which contains the binding for it. in the "wrong" code, the two lambdas are defined in the outer, enclosing environment. even if there are some definitions for the same names there, they are _not_ the internal definitions which we need them to point to.

Comment: in `even?-wrong-`, we _need_ the `o` in the first argument lambda to refer to the second argument lambda, not anything else (or even worse, nothing at all). same with the `e` in the second argument lambda, which we need to point at the first argument lambda. thanks for asking the questions, I've edited the answer with this clarification.

Comment: Thanks. I think the point that I get easily lost on is that I often fail to see why `(lambda (n) (if (= n 0) #t (o (- n 1))))` doesn't what `o` is. `e` and `o` are obviously in the same frame.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244129/discussion-between-will-ness-and-j-mini).

Comment: What a beautiful answer! It might also be worth to point out that the semantics of `let` aren’t just a shortcoming, they might very well be desired, e.g. to swap two variables as in `(let ((x y) (y x)) …)`. This is something that `letrec` cannot do (easily).

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with my version of everyone's favorite mutually recursive example, even-or-odd.

```
(define (even-or-odd x)
  (letrec ((internal-even? (lambda (n)
                             (if (= n 0) 'even
                                 (internal-odd? (- n 1)))))
           (internal-odd? (lambda (n)
                            (if (= n 0) 'odd
                                (internal-even? (- n 1))))))
    (internal-even? x)))
```

If you wrote that with `let` instead of `letrec`, you'd get an error that `internal-even?` in unbound.  The descriptive reason for why that is is that the expressions that define the initial values in a `let` are evaluated in a lexical environment before the variables are bound whereas `letrec` creates an environment with those variables first, just to make this work.

Now we'll have a look at how to implement `let` and `letrec` with lambda so you can see why this might be.

The implementation of `let` is fairly straightforward. The general form is something like this:

```
(let ((x value)) body)  -->  ((lambda (x) body) value)
```

And so `even-or-odd` written with a `let` would become:

```
(define (even-or-odd-let x)
  ((lambda (internal-even? internal-odd?)
     (internal-even? x))
   (lambda (n)
     (if (= n 0) 'even
         (internal-odd? (- n 1))))
   (lambda (n)
     (if (= n 0) 'odd
         (internal-even? (- n 1))))))
```

You can see that the bodies of internal-even? and internal-odd? are defined outside the scope of where those names are bound.  It gets an error.

To deal with this problem when you want recursion to work, `letrec` does something like this:

```
(letrec (x value) body)  -->  ((lambda (x) (set! x value) body) #f)
```

[Note: There's probably a much better way of implementing `letrec` but that's what I'm coming up with off the top of my head.  It'll give you the idea, anyway.]

And now `even-or-odd?` becomes:

```
(define (even-or-odd-letrec x)
  ((lambda (internal-even? internal-odd?)
     (set! internal-even? (lambda (n)
                (if (= n 0) 'even
                    (internal-odd? (- n 1)))))
     (set! internal-odd? (lambda (n)
               (if (= n 0) 'odd
                   (internal-even? (- n 1)))))
     (internal-even? x))
   #f #f))
```

Now `internal-even?` and `internal-odd?` are being used in a context where they've been bound and it all works.

Comment: "*You can see that the bodies of `internal-even?` and `internal-odd?` are defined outside the scope of where those names are bound. It gets an error.*" - Actually, I can't. Like I say, I think that I fundamentally misunderstand the evaluation rules.

Comment: Inside that function, talking about the version that's the expansion of the `let`, there is the expression (lambda (internal-even? internal-odd?) (internal-even? x)).  That lambda is what binds the variables internal-even? and internal-odd? and inside the body of that lambda is the only place they're defined.  But the arguments to that lambda, where those functions are created, also try to reference those variables and they are not in the lexical scope at that point.